# Encode two longs into another primitive in java

Tags: java, primitive

I have a `Tuple` object that holds 3 primitives: `Tuple(double, long, long)`. To avoid creating a huge amount of `Tuple`, I'm thinking using Trove library's primitive MAP, which would take two primitive as key and value. In my case, it would be `Map<double, some primitive>`.

My question: is it possible efficiently to encode the two `long` into a single primitive that I can store in the map, and later decode them?

Comment: Perhaps you can store you data as double[], long[], long[] for all your Tuples.

Comment: The tuples are sorted by `double`, and `long`s are just associated information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right, you **cannot** pack two 64-bit primitives into another primitive, which is at most 64 bits of size. Both, `double` and `long` by standard are mapped by 64 binary digits.

The question is, whether you can impose some *restrictions* on the **numbers** you are dealing with. If you know, you will always have *even* numbers or *uneven* numbers or the first component will have *integer range* or you are dealing with *multitudes of 1000*, you can win some bits here.

Practically speaking, you will *never* make use of all

> 2^64 x 2^64 combinations

of pairs of long values.

On the other hand, it's no big deal to handle maps on pairs of values. That was the whole effort to make object-oriented languages like Java to not only deal with data types like `struct` in **C**, but also to bind methods to the data.
You can find good implementations of a Pair class in the web, e.g. [angelikalanger.com](http://www.angelikalanger.com). Or you can easily code an implementation yourself, especially, since you only need a pair of `Long` values.
Also consider to use `Pair<Double, Pair<Long, Long>>` or implement a `Tuple<M,N,T>` class right away instead of a Map, i.e. key-value combination, following the outline of the `Pair<M,N>` implementation.

Finally, you could even employ an **in-memory database** like [H2](http://www.h2database.com) to hold your `Tuple(double, long, long)` entries. It is enough to enclose it in your project as a Java library and configure it properly.

By the way, a *3-tuple* is called a *triple*. Therefore, you could correctly call your `class Triple(double, long, long)` or better `Triple(Double, Long, Long)`.

Comment: What if I know the two `long` are both positive (0~2^63-1)?

Comment: If both numbers are positive, you win two bits, one each. (You could store both in 126 bits then.) That would only matter, if you pack both into a BigInteger or use a native (machine) data structure.

Comment: Your statement is very naïve. In information-theoretical fields like chaos theory or crptography, all bits in a (primitive) value will be used, Even if you don't use 2^65 different values, the handful of values that you do use have full 128-bit entropy, meaning all 128 bits should be accounted for and are incompressible. The latter statement also implies that even given 127 bits, the 128th bit is unpredictable (unless the entropy is 127 bits or less)

Answer (score 7):

> is it possible efficiently to encode the two long into a single primitive

No, simply because longs are 64-bit, and no Java primitive is longer than that. You would need a 128-bit primitive to encode two longs into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Trove's double-Object map and encode the two longs into a BigInteger, but if your objective is to stay strictly with primitive types, that obviously isn't any help.

Answer (score 0):

As Joonas says, there is no single primitive that will hold 128 bits.  What might meet your need is to use an array to hold the two longs: `Map<Double, long[]>`.  While `Double` and `long[]` are not strictly primitives that might suit.  Remember that you cannot put `double` (small-d) into a Map as Maps can only contain reference types, not primitives.

Alternatively, how about `Map(Double, Pair)`, where `Pair` is a small class to hold two longs?  Most libraries have something like that lying around somewhere.